# How to float grid view left side of the Sidebar (in HTML first appear posts)

Tags: html, css

I write a sample code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yazdi/MUU4V/2/)

I want exactly this Result but the **Sidebar** in **HTML** appear in bottom of code, like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>    
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>

    <div class="sidebar"></div> <---- coming bottom for SEO

</div>
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yazdi/MUU4V/2/),

Green box (Sidebar)

Gray box (Posts)

[image]

---

I found my Question , thanks **@David** for `dummy` idea, I use 2 big margin-right

http://jsfiddle.net/yazdi/MUU4V/9/

Comment: with JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: without JS, only with CSS

Comment: Please image (edited in photoshop or other)

Comment: the final image exactly like Result in jsfiddle, Just in HTML code sidebar coming bottom.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you plan on this site being responsive, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Question , thanks @David for `dummy` idea, I use 2 big `margin-right`

http://jsfiddle.net/yazdi/MUU4V/9/

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item margin">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item margin">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>    
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap {
    width: 372px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction:rtl;
    position: relative;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    height: 130px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 90px;
    height: 263px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 3px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty great combination of ideas as long as you can target those 2 divs. Nice. : )

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of a hack way to do this, but *it does work*, so it's worth saying.

You can manipulate the sidebar's position since we know the exact height of it.

---

I started off by floating the items to the left:

```
.item{
    float: left;
}
```

This put the sidebar on the right side.

---

Next I added 2 more items as a placeholder for the sidebar. To these, I assigned the `.dummy` class just to distinguish them in the code:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item dummy"></div>
<div class="item"></div>    
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item dummy"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

They are inserted at the 4th and 8th positions because that is where the sidebar is meant to be.

---

Finally, I used relative positioning to move the sidebar up 399px.

```
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 90px;
    height: 263px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 3px;

    position: relative;
    top: -399px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUU4V/3/)

---

### Edit:

Actually in hindsight, it is not necessary to float the items to the left. It works both ways.

### [Other JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUU4V/5/)

---

### Another Edit:

Since you pointed out that you do not have a static height, another approach would be to use absolute positioning inside a relative container. Since your rectangles are already nicely placed inside a container (`.wrap`), we can just assign relative positioning to that and force the sidebar to the top of the container:

```
.wrap
{
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

**This does still require the dummy items to work.**

### [Yet Another JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUU4V/7/)

Comment: I have problem with top: -399px; but dummy is a good idea, we can use big margin, thanks for dummy

Comment: @Sinac What is your issue with the `top:-399px;`?

Comment: I have not a static height! But dummy for margin is a good idea, I will write and show you, thanks

Comment: @Sinac Please check my edit. I made it work for any number of items.

Comment: @Sinac See this fiddle for an example with more rows: http://jsfiddle.net/MUU4V/8/

Comment: @Sinac Fair enough. Nice way to not need dummies.

Answer (score 1):

Here was my first reaction:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/MUU4V/6/)

### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>    
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item last-item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar"></div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 372px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction:rtl;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
}
.item {
    float: right;
    width: 90px;
    height: 130px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 263px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 3px;    
}

.last-item {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think `last-item` is not a good idea, because maybe we have several posts

Comment: Several posts huh - that would be smart to mention in the question for future reference. If your site is static, then this is not much of an issue in general. You can just use dream weaver - or make the entire site with absolute positioning. You don't really need to figure out an awesome "web" wide fix for such a specific problem when you already are giving up most of the fight.

Comment: maybe you could use nth-of-type(10) --- ?

Comment: nth-of-type not support in IE7! , I want convert HTML to WordPress, we can use `$i=0;` out LOOP and `$i++;` inside LOOP and `if($i=1 || $i=4){echo "margin";}` for print the `class` . Thank you for attention